# how can ODB support CString in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, odb

I'm trying use ODB in my program to save a class that contains CString type (a MFC variable type).
When I compile the include file with ODB, it tell me the 'CString' does not name a type.

There is 2 ways I think can solve it. I tried but failed.
1、Let ODB support the CString type
  I write a CString-traits.hxx reference the qt example and this web (https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/18/custom-database-to-cxx-type-mapping-in-odb/)，when I compile with ODB, the compiler want the CString support include file. I give the include file path, but the compiler want more include file that from the CString include file, and it appears more unsupport type. I think there must be sth wrong because it's so inconvenient.

2、Let ODB compiler ignore the 'CString' word
  I add the '#pragma db transient' before the CString, like below:

```
#pragma db transient
    CString name;
```

but the odb compiler also tell me the CString not name a type.

After all, my question is:
1、How can ODB support CString?
2、How can ODB compiler ignore particular sentence, such as sentence contains 'CString'?

Thinks

Comment: `CString` is not a type. It's a type alias. You might have better luck using the explicit class template instantiations `CStringA` and `CStringW`.

Comment: Thank you IInspectable.
I have tried CStringA, but ODB always search the include files (to support CStringA) and request new include or variable types.
I don't think ODB is so inconvenient, so there must be sth wrong in my code.